# What's the difference between anchor deploy and upgrade when updating existing programs?

Tags: anchor

From what I understand, `anchor deploy` will create the necessary accounts when deploying the first time. But I'm not sure what the difference is when I want to make updates to the program, whether I should just use `anchor deploy` again or what difference it makes if I use `anchor upgrade` instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've always been using `anchor deploy`, and it was automatically only upgrading if the same programID was already deployed before.

It seems older versions of `anchor deploy` by default always deployed a new programID, but for now, it automatically upgrades if an older version is already deployed.

A noteworthy difference is that `anchor upgrade` only deploys a *single* program, whereas `anchor deploy` deploys *each program* in the workspace.